# use mongo uuid in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the _id in mongo set to a uuid via node plug in "node-uuid" when I look at the value in robomongo it looks like this

```
"_id" : UUID("5fe6075a-8157-4dfc-8aab-3316ea9cbf17"),
```

however when I use mongoose to retrieve the value and send it to the client I get a lot of strange characters.

"*id":"*�\u0007Z�WM���3\u0016ꜿ\u0017"

the schema I'm using is

```
_id: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
},
```

is there anyway to make this work?

Thanks,

R

Comment: how are you creating the uuid ?, how you create and save the object? that 'UUID("5fe6075a-8157-4dfc-8aab-3316ea9cbf17")' that you see in robomongo is wrong.. seems like an object not like a String.. parsing the mixing or the object to String could be giving you some problems..

Comment: Top google result: [mongoose-uuid](https://github.com/dlamp/mongoose-uuid)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [uuid-mongodb](https://github.com/cdimascio/uuid-mongodb) module.

With this module, you can convert the BSON UUID (returned by Mongoose) to a string.

So, given your example, we assume the Mongoose query returns a document, `doc` whose `_id` field contains a BSON UUID value. To convert that UUID to a string, you can use [uuid-mongodb](https://github.com/cdimascio/uuid-mongodb) like so:

```
const uuidString = MUUID.from(doc._id).toString();
```

Once you have the UUID as a string, return it to the client

For more details, go [here](https://github.com/cdimascio/uuid-mongodb)

Comment: How did you do when you want mongoose to populate you UUID property with the UUID string by using populate() method ?